# Python: I can't figure out how to add a leaderboard feature on my code

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code right now:

```
from replit import db
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
from colorama import Fore, Style

from getkey import getkey, keys
import random

import time

from threading import Event

print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "Click or" + Fore.RED + " die" + Style.NORMAL)

# Check if the 'clicks' key exists in the database and load the value if it does
if 'clicks' in db:
  clicks = db['clicks']
else:
  clicks = 0

print("\n" + Fore.GREEN + "You have " + Style.BRIGHT + str(clicks) + Style.NORMAL + " clicks.")

while True:

  key = getkey()
  if key == ' ':
    gain = random.randint(1, 1000)
    clicks += gain
    db['clicks'] = clicks
    print(Fore.CYAN + "+" + Style.BRIGHT, gain)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    clear()  # clear the screen
    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "Click or" + Fore.RED + " die" + Style.NORMAL)
    print("\n" + Fore.GREEN + "You have " + Style.BRIGHT + str(clicks) + Style.NORMAL + " clicks.")
    time.sleep(0.2)

  elif key == 'l' or key == 'L':
    clear()  # clear the screen
    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "Click or" + Fore.RED + " die" + Style.NORMAL)
    print(Fore.YELLOW + Style.DIM + "\nLeaderboard:")
    leaderboard_keys = [k for k in db.keys() if k.startswith('clicks-')]
    for key in leaderboard_keys:
      username = key.split("-")[1]
      score = db[key]
      print(f"{username}: {score} clicks")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print("\n" + Fore.GREEN + "You have " + Style.BRIGHT + str(clicks) + Style.NORMAL + " clicks.")
    time.sleep(0.2)

  # Save click count to database on program exit
  elif key == keys.ESCAPE:
    db['clicks'] = clicks
    break
```

I need the leaderboard to output:
(Place in LB). (Name): (clicks)

Right now I get:

Click or die

Leaderboard:

You have 25287 clicks.

You have 25287 clicks should show up at the start or after clicking. Not on the leaderboard

```
type here
```

Comment: Upon first viewing, I am confused about the meaning of your leaderboard. Also I don't know the meaning of "clicks"? A bit more context regarding your goal would be very helpful before diving into your code.

Comment: I was messing around a little bit because I'm testing out how this stuff works. Clicks are my point system, so think of 1 click as 1 point. So I want my leaderboard to rank all the players who have played based on the amount of clicks (points) they have

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.